# Performance test on a webpage which loads data from multiple API's

Tags: jmeter

We have a webpage which will load data from multiple api's as configured by the users. While doing performance test of this page, In HTTP request I have added this page URL and executed the script. To my surprise, the script executed successfully with status as 200 as I dig into more I changed the drop down(In View Results Tree) from Text to HTML(Download Resources) and I don't see any page data in the response. Can someone help me with this. I'm not sure how to proceed with performance testing on this particular page.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser**
>
> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

My expectation is that your "multiple APIs" are triggered by JavaScript calls using [AJAX technology](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp). Given JMeter doesn't evaluate JavaScript it doesn't execute the AJAX requests which are being called by the real browser therefore you don't see the data coming from the APIs.

In order to get the browser-like behaviour you need to send the same requests which real browser sends, you can record them from the real browser using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)

Also be aware that real browsers execute AJAX requests in parallel, in order to properly simulate browser's network footprint you need to place the HTTP Request samplers representing these API requests under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)